Paging 3 Jetpack compose issue
In PagingSource class I see that the data been sent
LoadResult.Page(
            data = response, //<-- here data been sent
            prevKey = if (offset == 0) null else offset - limit,
            nextKey = nextKey
        )

Here is viewModel piece that suppose to catch the data from repo
    val customers:Flow<PagingData<MyData>> = myRepository.getMyData().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

And here is my Activity class
 lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.customers.collectLatest {pagingData ->
            myAdapter.submitData(pagingData) // here I dont receive anything
        }
    }

Where might be the issue?

Where is the jetpack compose? You submit your data to some adapter, that looks like recycler view, not compose...
